Postgres: queries are not finished although no lock blocks execution
we have two queries on the DB, one for updating, one for deleting existing entries. Since this is a manual locking mechanism, the table is called "lock". Accessing the lock table uses a separate DB connection pool for this table only, while all other tables are handled by another connection pool. Hikari is used as connection pool handler in a Spring Boot 3.2.7 application with Hibernate.
The database is an Azure-provided shared DB version "PostgreSQL 14.11 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit"
The queries are executed a couple 100K times/day, without any issue. But sometimes, the queries just stop being executed. Sadly, they queries will hold a lock on the table (or the rows), blocking other processes until starvation.
Running a select against pg_stat_activity, in this case results in something as the following:



datid
datname
pid
leader_pid
usesysid
usename
application_name
client_addr
client_hostname
client_port
backend_start
xact_start
query_start
state_change
wait_event_type
wait_event
state
backend_xid
backend_xmin
query_id
query
backend_type




24907
DB_NAME
15227
[NULL]
24946
USER_NAME
PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
IP
[NULL]
PORT
2024-08-12 05:37:18.946394+02
2024-08-12 06:00:06.278136+02
2024-08-12 06:00:06.278541+02
2024-08-12 06:00:06.278542+02
[NULL]
[NULL]
active
525841325
525840266
-3234940509960012845
update lock set lock_indicator=$1,lock_acquired_timestamp_utc=$2,expiration_timestamp_utc=$3 where queue_process_uuid=$4 and expiration_timestamp_utc>$5 and not exists(select 1 from lock l2_0 where lock.vehicle_id=l2_0.vehicle_id and l2_0.lock_indicator=$6) and (queue_process_uuid,amount_entries_requested)=(select l3_0.queue_process_uuid,count(l3_0.queue_process_uuid) from lock l3_0 where l3_0.queue_process_uuid=lock.queue_process_uuid and l3_0.expiration_timestamp_utc=lock.expiration_timestamp_utc and (l3_0.vehicle_id,l3_0.process_timestamp_utc)=(select l4_0.vehicle_id,min(l4_0.process_timestamp_utc) from lock l4_0 where l3_0.vehicle_id=l4_0.vehicle_id group by 1) group by l3_0.queue_process_uuid,l3_0.amount_entries_requested)
client backend


24907
DB_NAME
14823
[NULL]
24946
USER_NAME
PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
IP
[NULL]
PORT
2024-08-12 05:35:54.689064+02
2024-08-12 06:03:32.052952+02
2024-08-12 06:03:32.053204+02
2024-08-12 06:03:32.053204+02
Lock
tuple
active
525857553
525841224
-7889739752121511551
delete from lock where expiration_timestamp_utc<$1 and queue_process_uuid<>$2 and vehicle_id in(select l2_0.vehicle_id from lock l2_0 where l2_0.queue_process_uuid=$3)
client backend


24907
DB_NAME
15319
[NULL]
24946
USER_NAME
PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
IP
[NULL]
PORT
2024-08-12 05:37:37.947744+02
2024-08-12 06:05:02.861719+02
2024-08-12 06:05:02.861758+02
2024-08-12 06:05:02.861791+02
Client
ClientRead
idle in transaction
[NULL]
525841224
[NULL]
select v1_0.id,v1_0.vin,v1_0.country,v1_0.active,v1_0.geotimtestamp from vehicle v1_0 where v1_0.id=$1 and v1_0.active=true and v1_0.import_version=(select max(v2_0.import_version) from vehicle v2_0 where v2_0.vin=v1_0.vin and v2_0.active=true) order by v1_0.modificationtimestamp desc
client backend



The issue occurs for both, the update and the delete statement. If the pid is killed, all the other processes resume their activity immediately and finish within ms - even the other update/delete statements doing the same thing as the blocked one.
Sometimes, there is just one of those update/delete statements (because a previous execution did not conclude), sometimes there are multiple (in this case: 2 updates, 2 selects, 18 deletes).
The lock table at that point of time sometimes contains just a handful of entries, sometimes a low 4-digit amount. On the other hand, it often works for days with the same amount of entries/workload.
Here's the lock table's definition:
CREATE TABLE public."lock" (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    queue_process_uuid uuid NOT NULL,
    vehicle_id int4 NULL,
    expiration_timestamp_utc timestamptz NOT NULL,
    process_timestamp_utc timestamptz NOT NULL,
    lock_indicator uuid NOT NULL,
    amount_entries_requested int4 NOT NULL,
    lock_acquired_timestamp_utc timestamptz NULL,
    lock_requester int4 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT lock_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT lock_vehicle_fkey FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_id) REFERENCES public.vehicle(id)
);
CREATE INDEX idx_lock_expiration_ts ON public.lock USING btree (expiration_timestamp_utc);
CREATE INDEX idx_lock_process_ts ON public.lock USING btree (process_timestamp_utc);
CREATE INDEX idx_lock_queue_process_uuid ON public.lock USING btree (queue_process_uuid);
CREATE INDEX idx_lock_vehicle_id ON public.lock USING btree (vehicle_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_u_lock_lock_indicator ON public.lock USING btree (lock_indicator, vehicle_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_u_lock_process_indicator ON public.lock USING btree (queue_process_uuid, vehicle_id);

It would be great, if you could give us any hint, since we've run out of ideas.
Thanks.
kniffte

I suspect the unique indexes you have are the culprit as those need to be updated/checked and that has to be atomic and can not be done concurrently. See also https://rcoh.me/posts/postgres-unique-constraints-deadlock/ . You also don't need additional indexes on queue_process_uuid and vehicle_id afaik as those are already indexed with the unique index.

@M.Deinum thanks for your response. We've changed the implementation in an effort to remove the unique constraints. The change is on our integration environment now - now we'll wait a couple days.
Sadly, not seeing the issue re-appear, doesn't mean it's solved. But it makes sense - thanks so far. We'll keep you updated :)
